# Как заменить window.onload на DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript

Пишу расширение для хрома, которое внедряет сторонний js на страницу.

```
window.onload = function() {
//содержимое расширения
}
```

В таком варианте всё работает, но приходится ждать, пока загрузятся картинки/гифки и т.п.

Захотел ускорить работу расширения и перевести на DOMContentLoaded, но ни один из примеров, найденных в интернете, у меня не работает. Ошибок нет, просто расширение не работает.

```
function ready() {
  //содержимое расширения
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Вот пример варианта, который пробую, но он не работает. Почему? И как исправить?

Comment: Вероятно, потому что ваше расширение отрабатывает уже после того, как событие DOMContentLoaded случилось https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233115

Comment: Спасибо,  после этого я просто удалил window.onload -- и стало заметно лучше. Уже хотя бы не прогружаются тяжёлые медиа-файлы типа гифок, а страницы листаются быстрее. Но всё равно без setTimeount 700+ почему-то код срабатывать не успевает. т.е. страницы перелисывает, а внутри страниц ничего делать не успевает (те же алерты не срабатывают).

Answer (score 1):

оставить так ?

```
function ready() {
  //содержимое расширения
}

ready()
```

Comment: Так уже частично работает. Но прочитав предыдущий комментарий (и узнав, что можно в манифесте настроить, когда будет работать код), я просто удалил window.onload и всё так же частично работает. 

Проблема в том, что по страницам расширение переходить может быстро (не загружая информацию), а вот сам код, который должен срабатывать на новых страницах, срабатывать не успевает (те же алереты). Пока что стоит костыль в виде setTimeout 700 -- но хотелось бы, чтобы страницы листались быстрее (и при этом код работал)...